# Java design pattern about web page loading

Tags: java, design-patterns

Now, your Browser object loads a Webpage, a Webpage uses Text and Image objects. I found out that in this implementation, a Webpage would not be presented/visualized/shown to the users unless all Text and Image objects have been completely downloaded from the remote website.  That is, if a webpage includes a very big image that needs longer time to be downloaded, your Browser would not show the Webpage to the users until it has finished downloading all data.

What design pattern should I apply to this situation?

Comment: _I found out that in this implementation, a Webpage would not be presented/visualized/shown to the users unless all Text and Image objects have been completely downloaded from the remote website_ - is this correct? What about Ajax? How does single-page application like facebook work?

Comment: Might be a better question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Images and other resources are handled by different GET requests, so your page HTML content will load even if the images won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy design pattern is useful here.

For images you can have proxies to represent them. You can put the placeholders for expensive images to download. When your page downloads, the text along with image placeholders will get downloaded and your page will be shown quickly and the actual images will be downloaded lazily without stopping the page being shown.

Check [Proxy Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/proxy-pattern.html) especially **Virtual Proxy**

Comment: how about the original situation that we should show the webpage until the image and text was loaded? what design pattern should i apply?

Comment: that depends on the browser, it is the browser that should not wait for all data to come up before displaying (and they are infact very smart now). I dont think that any pattern from server side could help :|